# LINQ Query Causing Exit Sub or Swallowing Error

Tags: vb.net, linq

My code is as follows:

```
    Using _EntityModel As New AboveNemaSalesDatabaseEntities()

        Dim _SelectActiveOptionCodes = (From _OptCodes In _EntityModel.tblOptionCodes
                                       Where _OptCodes.fdStatus = "A"
                                       Select _OptCodes.fdDescription, _OptCodes.fdOptionCode).ToList()

        Dim _SelectActiveOptionCodes2 = (From _OptCodes In _EntityModel.tblOptionCodes
                                       Where _OptCodes.fdStatus = "A"
                                       Select New optionCodes With {.description = _OptCodes.fdDescription,
                                                                    .optionCode = _OptCodes.fdOptionCode})

        sortableOptionCodes = _SelectActiveOptionCodes2
        sortedOptionCodes = _SelectActiveOptionCodes2

        OptionCodeListBox.DataSource = sortedOptionCodes
        OptionCodeListBox.DisplayMember = "fdDescription"
        OptionCodeListBox.ValueMember = "fdOptionCode"

    End Using
```

The first query works fine and returns a list in the format [index]{description = "descritption here", optionCode = "option code here"}

The second query creates but when it is called to save to my custom class the program exits the sub or swallows an error. Stepping through the code, the line starting with sortedOptionCodes and after never runs.

Comment: What kind of object is `sortableOptionCodes`?

Comment: optionCodes object. It is a custom class created. I think I have found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I was dealing with is that my query was producing a list of optionCodes and my variable was not prepared to store this.

Old variables:

```
Dim sortableOptionCodes As optionCodes
Dim sortedOptionCodes As optionCodes
```

New variables:

```
Dim sortableOptionCodes As List(Of optionCodes)
Dim sortedOptionCodes As List(Of optionCodes)
```

I also added a .ToList() function to the end of the second query.